# Silverlight Combobox Issue

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, combobox

I am trying to use a combobox inside a datagrid, but I am running into an issue.  Here is the code:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="6,71,6,0"  Name="dgridDeptNums" Loaded="dgridDeptNums_Loaded" Height="226" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Speciality" Width="*">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Department, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <ComboBox.Items>
                                    <ComboBoxItem>Information Technology</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem>Human Resources</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem>Engineering</ComboBoxItem>
                                 etc...
                                </ComboBox.Items> 
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="# of Supervisors" Binding="{Binding Providers, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="# of Managers" Binding="{Binding Midlevels, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"/>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

The issue is that I want to databind the department, but all I get is System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.  I am sure I am missing something here, so any help is appreciated.

Wade

Comment: What type is "Department"? Is it a string or is it a class of your own making? Since your items are not bound (only the selected value is), you may be trying to select a value that is not of the same type as your items list.

Comment: @SirDemon Department is part of a class or my own making and it is a string.

Comment: then you should probably try michael s scherotters answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of 
`<ComboBoxItem>Information Technology</ComboBoxItem>`

use 
`<sys:string>Information Technology</sys:string>`

where

`xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: Do I need to keep that within the <ComboBox.Items> tag?

Comment: "sys:string" should be "sys:String" (notice the capitalization) in SL 4.

Comment: It took me a while to realize that you don't use the <ComoBoxItem> syntax to get it to work. Example: <ComboBox SelectedValue="Manual" Width="200" Height="22"><sys:String>Auto</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Manual</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Other</sys:String>
        </ComboBox>